# Nhibernate Linq Get<T> object by name not by Id

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate

```
public T FindById(object id)
{
     return session.Get<T>(id);
}
```

I want to get object by *Name*

Something like this, but I am not able to write a query with type `T`

```
session.Get<T>().Where(x => x.something == something).SingleOrDefault();
```

or is there any alternative to this approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Expression` trees and build something like:

```
protected T Get<T, TValue>(string propertyName, TValue value) where T : class
{
    var par = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
    var eq = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Equal(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Property(par, propertyName), System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Constant(value));
    var lambda = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(eq, par);
    return session.QueryOver<T>().Where(lambda).SingleOrDefault();
}
```

Note that I'm using the full namespace + classname because NHibernate has another `Expression` class.

Answer (score 2):

There is a native solution in NHiberante:

#### [Chapter 15. Criteria Queries](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#querycriteria)

This Criteria API *(which is there from the beginning)* is really what we need here. For example the `QueryOver` API - is built on top of that.

The biggest benefit is, it does work natively with "strings". This would be very simple, easy to maintain piece of code:

```
public T GetByProperty<T>(string propertyName, object value)
    where T: class
{
    var session = ... // get a session
    return session.CreateCriteria<T>()
        .Add(Restrictions.Eq(propertyName, value))
        .SetMaxResults(1)
        .List<T>()
        .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

There is a complete [doc](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#querycriteria)

Answer (score 1):

You have to restrict T to something with a particular property. You could, for instance, create a superclass called NamedObject which has a property Name and make all nameable objects inherit from it. Restricting T to a NameableObject or descendant would then allow you to access the Name property in your query.

Not particularly elegant but it should work.

Comment: Thanks simon waiting for something else or i will try this .

Comment: True, yes. Probably better in fact!

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use reflection for query a generic type, just like this:

```
session.Get<T>().Where(P => typeof(P).GetPropery("PropertyName").GetValue(P).ToString() == "Something").SingleOrDefault();
```

In this code, `typeof(oObject)` returns de a `Type` intance of the object, then the `GetProperty("PropertyName")` method returns you a `System.Reflection.PropertyInfo` with that you can get the property value with `GetValue(P)` method that receive an instance of the object that contain the property in this case is [P] create in Lamba expression.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure what you mean by *"I am not able to write a query with type T"*.
But you can call with expression where refactor is supported.

```
public T GetByExpression<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> restriction) where T : class
{
    return Session.QueryOver<T>().Where(restriction).SingleOrDefault();
}
```